# Momentjs doesn't work on Firefox 28.0

Tags: javascript, firefox, momentjs

in firefox that code doesn't work [(jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/uGUu8/)

it return false

```
var m1 = moment("Lunedì, 14 Aprile 2014 07:40");
console.log(
    m1.isSame("14 Aprile 2014", 'day')
);
```

in chrome it return true.

some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that works fine

```
 m1.isSame(moment("14 Aprile 2014", 'DD MMMM YYYY', 'it').format(), 'day')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uGUu8/2/

thanks at all

Answer (score 3):

Without any formatting hints, the only format moment.js will attempt to parse on its own is the ISO-8601 standard.  Otherwise, it requires a formatting hint, or it will just let the browser attempt to parse it the same as if you had used the `Date` object - which is highly implementation specific.

From [the moment.js docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/):

> **Warning** Browser support for this is inconsistent. Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.
>
> For more consistent results, you should use String + Format.
>
> There is one exception: Moment.js does detect if you are using an ISO-8601 string and will parse that correctly without a format string.

So, if you expect text in a particular format, then you should use a format hint:

```
moment.lang("it")
moment("Lunedì, 14 Aprile 2014 07:40","LLLL")
```

The `"LLLL"` format is the "long" form of the localized format for the language - Italian in this case.  You could also provide the specific format string, such as:

```
moment.lang("it")
moment("Lunedì, 14 Aprile 2014 07:40","dddd, DD MMMM YY HH:mm")
```